# How to manage server user session within client side single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, session, single-page-application

I've been fumbling around with different client side technologies, like AngularJS, EmberJS, even trying to use straight JQuery and figure out how to use ReactJS with it. That aside, my goal is to build a single page app using json in between the client and a Java Jersey 2 jax-rs back end api.

I have two stumbling blocks right now. Some info though..I am deploying my app as a WAR file in Jetty. My back end is java based. I am using only jquery in the client side as of now.

My main stumbling block is how to handle login, logout and session management. With an rest API and using ajax, I have login working, including it setting a cookie. My concern however is with a single page app, there is just the one index page, and if the user closes the browser, then reopens it to the index page while the cookie/session is still good, the user should be logged in, not see the outside (not logged in) page. I am unsure how to handle this, whether it be a jsp page, index.html with some templating library, etc. With JSP I can insert some scriplet code (against my better judgment). In the old days I'd include a header that would check for request.getSession().getAttribute("user") and if it was there..the user was logged in and using scriplet if() code I'd display a logged in header, instead of the non-logged in header. But I am in the belief there has got to be a better way to do this with todays client side JS frameworks.

The other stumbling block is the navigation and dynamic aspects. For example, when I was messing around with angular js, it was easy enough to use Welcome {{name}} and within the scope replace name with a json response value for the logged in user. In my current situation, I am not exactly sure how to best go about displaying dynamic bits like this with pure jquery other than using some sort of $("#elem-id").innerHtml="..." code within the response success method of an ajax call. As well, I am not quite sure how to handle navigation to different pages. My logged in site will have some drop down menus or links that will replace the content area with different varying amounts of content.

So first, what are some ways in a SPA to handle user sessions, in the case of a page reload, or close/crash browser restart.. to ensure the user is still logged in and direct them to the right page?  Second, what sort of templating and routing/navigation options exist that don't require me to put a huge ton of code in my one index.jsp page?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't think its a long story, who is free to read this? Try to short your problem, or give us some code which you tried.

Comment: @Rohan.. not sure how you answered my question? I've seen much much longer questions on here. I feel I gave the details needed. If that's too much, don't read it. Nobody is forcing you to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're having a REST API as the back end, then you must have implemented oAuth as an authentication mechanism. That is, when your user logs in, using a username and a password, you exchange that data with an authentication token. This authentication token is sent your server with each and every API call and your backend validates this token before servicing the request. Clear so far?

What you could do is, when you obtain the access token, you can also obtain the access token expiration time from the server and store that data in your client side app. In localStorage maybe? And when your user closes the browser and reopens again, you can first check whether such access token is available (and not expired) before asking the user to log in. This should solve your first problem.

Secondly, if you're looking for a lightweight routing option, I recommend [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director).

Comment: I think I am doing something along the lines of what you are saying. Although in my case.. at least with my jquery use right now, on document load I do a GET check to an API to see if the user is logged in. Perhaps a better choice is to read the document.cookie and look for my server specific cookie, rather than an ajax request on load? The idea behind ajax request on load was that the request, if a cookie is present, would allow the ajax handler to use the cookie and verify if the user/session is valid, not timed out, etc.

Comment: Well, since you're validating your user's auth token on every request, why would you want to check if the user is logged on explicitly?

Comment: I've actually changed how I do this. I have the luxury to not need to support IE9 or earlier, so decided that I am going to use local storage for storing a session token, and if the page is reloaded, I check for the session token upon page load and if found, redirect the user to their logged in dashboard. If the user selects logout I'll remove the session token. If for example they come back hours later, during the check if it's expired, it will be removed and they'll be at the main page again, where they can then log in again.

Comment: That is the best approach to do it. I have done it the same way. I also maintain the expiration time on the localstorage as well. That way, if it's expired, I don't need a call to the server to redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: That's a good point... I'll add that in. From what I understand, localStorage is safe in that it can only be accessed by javascript from the same server. Is there any chance though that client side could modify the localStorage timestamp value? It shouldn't matter as every request should validate the session token + time stamp anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, no. If there's a browser vulnerability like that, I guess you'd have bigger problems :)

Answer (score 2):

I am building a similar application. OAuth is not mandatory. You can have normal sessions etc by hitting the jersey login endpoint and setting a session and a cookie "keepme" with the session if user wants to be persistently logged in. You can then have a jersey AuthFilter for example check if either there is a cookie with a valid session or an active session and keep the user logged in.

Your frontend application should have no say over this, just communicate with the server and if it doesn't get unauthorized access (from the AuthFilter) then continues otherwise it displays the login page.